# How can I set a specific Operating System to boot using bash (UEFI)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bash, uefi

I want to create a Script that, when executed, changes the boot order to boot a specific operating system with a known partition, like the MacOS "Start Volume" setting. Is there any way this can be accomplished?

Requirements for the Software
-Does the Job specified above
-Command-line
-Open-Source

Comment: Did you want to have it change the boot order on a permanent basis until you change it again?  Or do you want it like on a one time basis so that the next reboot goes back to the default boot?

Answer (score 2):

All you need are 2 commands:

```
grub-set-default {NUMBER}    
update-grub
```

where `{NUMBER}` is the one you want to boot into.

Change `{NUMBER}` to a variable, put these 2 in a script, execute with `sudo {file} {number}`.

Comment: Don't forget that {NUMBER} is zero-based :)

Comment: You need to change GRUB_DEFAULT=saved in /etc/default/grub too. See the man page, man grub-set-default for using the menu title or id instead of a number, to allow access to submenu items.